# jQuery fast hover in out keeps trigering events even after stoping mouse

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have a div whose width is varied through jquery animation. But jQuery's hover function keeps trigging even when I stop mouse after fast in outs of mouse pointer. See the running code below and fastly move mouse couple of times and then stop mouse, you will see events keep triggering. How can I fix this. Animation at slower speed is needed can't remove it as a fix.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(".xixouter").hover(function() {
$(".xixouter").animate({ width: "95%"}, 500, "swing");
$(".contextent").animate({ opacity: "1"}, 450);///
//$('.contextent').css("opacity","1"); 
},
function() {
//$('.contextent').css("opacity","0");  
$(".contextent").animate({opacity: "0"}, 450); ////
$(".xixouter").animate({width: "240px"}, 500, "swing");  
}); 
});
```

```css
.xixouter{
position:relative;
padding: 15px;
height: 100px;
width: 240px;
margin:0px auto;
overflow:hidden;
    background: red;
}
.contextent{
padding: 40px !important;
display:block;
opacity: 0;
color: #555;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="xixouter">
<span class="contextent">
content
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use queue: false

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(".xixouter").hover(function() {
$(".xixouter").animate({ 
   width: "95%"}, 
   {queue: false }, 500, "swing");
$(".contextent").animate({ opacity: "1"}, {queue: false }, 450);
},
function() {
$(".contextent").animate({opacity: "0"}, {queue: false }, 450);
$(".xixouter").animate({width: "240px"}, {queue: false }, 500, "swing");  
}); 
});
```

```css
.xixouter{
position:relative;
padding: 15px;
height: 100px;
width: 240px;
margin:0px auto;
overflow:hidden;
    background: red;
}
.contextent{
padding: 40px !important;
display:block;
opacity: 0;
color: #555;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="xixouter">
<span class="contextent">
content
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before each `.animate()` to stop all running animations for selected elements:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f19yobqs/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(".xixouter").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(".xixouter").stop().animate(
            {
                width: "95%"
            }, 500, "swing");
            $(".contextent").stop().animate(
            {
                opacity: "1"
            }, 450);
        },
        function()
        { 
            $(".contextent").stop().animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            }, 450);
            $(".xixouter").stop().animate(
            {
                width: "240px"
            }, 500, "swing");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem and what ultimately helped me out with it was using the advice from [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/).  Here they break down why the stop solution works.  They also introduce the technique of checking if an element is still animating before performing another animation.

Also, you can use the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.  It does all the dirty work and makes sure that a person stops on an element before the animation initiates.  This means that an animation does not automatically begin when hovering, it will begin when stopping. It just depends on what you want to do.